# Duplicated Values with GROUP_CONCAT - CI

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, group-concat

I have some problem with a table that I want to build.
This table use a mysql database with mutliple tables linked by many-to-many tables.

I use JSON code to insert values in the jQuery Table.

Here is the model used to query the values in database :

```
function list_all()
    {
        $login_id = $this->session->userdata('User_id');
        $this->db->select('p.project_id, p.Project, p.Description, p.Status, p.Thumbnail, p.StartDate, p.EndDate, t.template_id, t.Template')
    ->select('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT v.Name SEPARATOR ",") as PeopleList, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT w.asset_id SEPARATOR ",") as AssetsList', FALSE)
    ->from('projects p')
    ->join('assigned_projects_ppeople a', 'a.project_id = p.project_id')
    ->join('assigned_assets_pproject w', 'w.project_id = p.project_id', 'left')
    ->join('project_templates t', 't.template_id = p.template_id')
    ->join('people v', 'v.people_id = a.people_id')
    ->where('a.people_id', $login_id)
    ->group_by('p.project_id');

    $query = $this->db->get();

        $rows = $query->result_array();

        //Return result to jTable
        $jTableResult = array();
        $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
        $jTableResult['Records'] = $rows;
            $result = json_encode($jTableResult);
        return $result;
    }
```

All values are well listed in the jQuery table, except GROUP_CONCAT values which are duplicated for People Name by the number of assets listed in Assets column...
EDIT : Problem resolved using DISTINCT keyword in GROUP_CONCAT.

But, if there's no entry assets linked to a project, the project doesn't be loaded and doesn't appear in table. EDIT : Resolved using LEFT JOIN on "assigned_assets_pproject" table.

Here is the screenshot of the table with JSON code https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEj4D.png
For information, there's just one user "Michael Bonfill" in each project.

Here is the output of last_query()

```
SELECT `p`.`project_id`, `p`.`Project`, `p`.`Description`, `p`.`Status`, `p`.`Thumbnail`, `p`.`StartDate`, `p`.`EndDate`, `t`.`template_id`, `t`.`Template`, GROUP_CONCAT(v.Name SEPARATOR ", ") as PeopleList, GROUP_CONCAT(w.asset_id SEPARATOR ", ") as AssetsList 
FROM (`projects` p) 
JOIN `assigned_projects_ppeople` a ON `a`.`project_id` = `p`.`project_id` 
JOIN `assigned_assets_pproject` w ON `w`.`project_id` = `p`.`project_id` 
JOIN `project_templates` t ON `t`.`template_id` = `p`.`template_id` 
JOIN `people` v ON `v`.`people_id` = `a`.`people_id` 
WHERE `a`.`people_id` = '1' 
GROUP BY `p`.`project_id`
```

I can export the SQL of my database for more info if you want.
Thank you !

Comment: your active record code is a mess...you set everything up, then set it up again..did you forget a get()? use echo $this->db->last_query() to see what your query is

Comment: Yes I know I can simplify the active record using Method Chaining... I tried to delete the second GROUP_CONCAT with its FROM and JOIN, and without that all works fine, so the error will come from here...

Comment: no, that's not what I'm saying. Your code is a mess - we don't use two from() expressions normally, but you don't look like you are joining them properly, is prolly where you are getting multiple rows. Use ONE from() clause and then join() and then you can see your sql correctly

Comment: I edited my question, now I have my number of People Name multiplied by the number of assets listed for the current row. And if there's no assets linked to a project, the project doesn't appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **DISTINCT** keyword like that `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT v.Name SEPARATOR ",")`

Comment: I believed DISTINCT was a GROUP_CONCAT keyword by default, and there was no need to write it each time we use GROUP_CONCAT. A big mistake for me :/ Thanks, everything works fine !

Comment: Unfortunately, I realise the problem is not completly solved... If I don't have any assets linked to a project, the project doesn't appear in the table. Where is the problem ?

Comment: Try **LEFT JOIN** for assigned_assets_pproject join

Comment: I never used LEFT or RIGHT JOIN, I think it's the moment to study better SQL language for me. Thank you Lighta everything work now ! ;)